# .net 6 & HTML 304 Not Modified

Tags: html, .net-6.0

I have created a .net 6 project with some static files. How do I configure it so these files will be work with the HTTP status "304 Not Modified"?

Comment: Q: Is your issue resolved?  Did my response help?  If not, please 1) clarify exactly how/where HTTP 304 is occurring, and why you believe it's necessarily a "problem"; 2) Show us the relevant code in your app.

Comment: Sorry @paulsm4, I just saw you're question. Your answer did help me resolve my problem. It took me a while to say so because I was researching why my CSS files were not caching and still haven't, but your answer was a big help and I appreciate you.

Comment: Cool - thank you.  Regarding cache behavior: 1) This is largely a function of the server. 2) look at the [cache-control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) HTTP header, 3) Look at the responses in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73989859/net-6-html-304-not-modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If your site has static files, you need to call `app.UseStaticFiles()` in your Startup.cs > Configure() method.
2. An HTTP status 304 is a Good Thing: it's just the server's way of telling the browser it's OK to reload the content from browser cache, rather than incurring the overhead of transferring everything from the server again.  It improves an app's responsiveness.
3. Here are some useful links:

- [Response Caching Middleware in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware)
- [Static files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files)
- [304 Not Modified - MDN.com](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/304)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was missing the options in the static files middleware which was causing the problem. I am still having trouble where some files (for example .css files) are not being cached, but it seemed the main problem was the missing options for the static files middleware.